# Convert WebM/H.264 to MP4/H.264 efficiently with ffmpeg.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, ffmpeg, webrtc

As a result of the answer here: [Recording cross-platform (H.264?) videos using WebRTC MediaRecorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45221112/recording-cross-platform-h-264-videos-using-webrtc-mediarecorder)

How can one go about using `ffmpeg.js` to efficiently unwrap a `webm` `h.264` video and re-wrap it into an `mp4` container?

I'm looking through the docs: https://github.com/Kagami/ffmpeg.js?files=1

However I don't see (or perhaps I'm looking for the wrong terminology) any examples for the above.  This operation will be performed on the browser (chrome) prior to uploading as a `Blob` - I could use a web worker though hopefully rewrapping is a trivial enough operation to not require it.

Comment: Are you sure the WebM files contain H.264 video? I would expect VP9 or VP8 video.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard per the answer in the linked question, Chrome can indeed record webm/h.264

Comment: I've never encountered such a file, and ffmpeg does not allow muxing of H.264 into WebM, but if you think you have such a combination/abomination then perhaps ffmpeg will be willing to demux it and mux it into MP4. I know nothing of `ffmpeg.js`, but the ffmpeg command would be: `ffmpeg -i input.webm -c:v copy -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4` or similar.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard ha!  thank you.  I'm new to ffmpeg / video formats so it's good to know that's an odd pair.